# No pointer type error for shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am using this method to get a `shared_ptr<>` from an object:

```
virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar<T>> iterator() const override{
        auto iter = std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo(*this));
        return iter;
    }
```

where Bar is a a base class of Foo. Foo isnt a template class, while Bar is.
I am getting an error here:

```
auto i = object.iterator();
while (i->hasNext()){
        std::cout << i->next()<<std::endl;
    }
```

which says:

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::shared_ptr<Bar<int> >'
     while (i->hasNext()){
             ^
```

since shared_ptr should support the `->` operator I don't realy understand why I am getting this error.

Edit:
`Foo` is an inner class of a class `Stack` like this:

```
        template<typename T>
        class Stack{
        public:
            virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar<T>> iterator() const override{
                    auto iter = std::make_shared<Foo>(Foo(*this));
                    return iter;
                }

        private:
            class Foo: public Bar<T>{
                virtual const T& next(){}
                virtual Boolean hasNext(){}

            };
        };
```

And class Bar:

```
template<typename T>
class Bar:{
public:
    virtual const T& next()=0;
    virtual Boolean hasNext()=0;

};
```

Compiler is MinGW in Clion on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Show us `Bar` class template (or the specialization which you use).

Comment: can you post a minimal, complete example? Just the class hierarchy with the 2 methods in question

Comment: Looks like a misleading diagnostic text. Probably the compiler is right there it shouldn't compile, but reports an incorrect cause.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5Zf9GBR5 compiles fine with VS2012